# python BeautifulSoup searching a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My first post here, I'm trying to find all  tags in this specific html and i can't get them out, this is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

url = "http://www.jutarnji.hr"
html_doc = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
soup.prettify()
soup.find_all("a", {"class":"black"})
```

find function returns [], but i see that there are  tags with class:"black" in the html, do I miss something?

Thanks,
Vedran

Comment: What python version / library version / os are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

I also had same problem.

**Try**

```
soup.findAll("a",{"class":"black"})
```

instead of

```
soup.find_all("a",{"class":"black"})
```

soup.findAll() works well for me.

Comment: Also works with other elements like : soup.findAll("label",{"for":"Form_CompanyName"})

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work for me, so I'd say that the problem is with your html document.

I tried to run the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<html>
 <body>
  <a class="black">
   <b>
    text1
   </b>
   <c>
    text2
   </c>
  </a>
  <a class="micio">
  </a>
  <a class="black">
  </a>
 </body>
</html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
soup.prettify()
print(soup.find_all("a", {"class":"black"}))
```

And as output I got:

```
[<a class="black">
<b>
    text1
   </b>
<c>
    text2
   </c>
</a>, <a class="black">
</a>]
```

---

**Edit:** As [@Puneet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949261/1132524) has pointed out, the problem might be the lack of a white space between the attributes in the html you're fetching.

I tried for instance to change the example above to something like:

```
html_doc = """<html>
 <body>
  <aclass="black">

# etc.. as before
```

And I got an empty list as result: `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the website's class tags arent separated from the end of the href attribute value with a space. BeautifulSoup doesnt seem to handle this very well. A reproducable test case is the following

```
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://www.jutarnji.hr/crkva-se-ogradila-od--cjenika--don-mikica--osim-krizme--sve-druge-financijske-obveze-su-neprihvatljive/1018314/" class="black">').prettify()
'<a href="http://www.jutarnji.hr/crkva-se-ogradila-od--cjenika--don-mikica--osim-krizme--sve-druge-financijske-obveze-su-neprihvatljive/1018314/" class="black">\n</a>'
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://www.jutarnji.hr/crkva-se-ogradila-od--cjenika--don-mikica--osim-krizme--sve-druge-financijske-obveze-su-neprihvatljive/1018314/"class="black">').prettify()
''
```

Answer (score 0):

it seams that using lxml solves the problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from urllib import urlopen

url = "http://www.jutarnji.hr"
html_doc = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

soup.find_all("a", {"class":"black"})
```