# The \n is not translating to an endline in my output from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn BeautifulSoup and I have no prior experience with it, I am testing the implementation from the answer for this question -> [python BeautifulSoup searching a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947957/python-beautifulsoup-searching-a-tag)

However my output doesn't match the output that they list as the `\n` is not translating into a new line. What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Input:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<html>
 <body>
  <a class="black">
   <b>
    text1
   </b>
   <c>
    text2
   </c>
  </a>
  <a class="micio">
  </a>
  <a class="black">
  </a>
 </body>
</html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
soup.prettify()
print soup.find_all("a", {"class":"black"})
```

Output:

```
[<a class="black">\n<b>\n    text1\n   </b>\n<c>\n    text2\n   </c>\n</a>, <a class="black">\n</a>]
```

Comment: I think this is solely due differences in python 2 vs. python 3. In python 3 it seems when printing it parses the `\n`'s in the list as a new line in the console while in python2 it shows the `\n`'s

Comment: When you print a list, it prints the representation of the list elements, not the values.

Comment: @Karl No, `print(["abc\ndef"])` prints `\n` in Python 3 as well.

Comment: @Barmar well there is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3, just try it yourself and when using Python 3 it outputs it like expected from the link. But when using Python 2 it outputs what was posted in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to output the text in the tags then you might as well iterate through the list return by the `find_all` method

```
all = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"black"})
for i in all:
    print(i.text)
```

This returns the text of the tags with whitespaces which can be cleaned